# Mugshot don't recognize user password

Tags: xfce, 15.04

I've created a user for my wife on xfce and when she assigns a picture to her user in Mugshot and confirms her password it says the password is wrong, shes using her login password, that's the one right? I'm on Xunbuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the user as to be part of the sudo group to set the picture, so i added the user to sudo group,logged in with that user, added the user picture on mugshot, and then removed it from the sudo group. 
Now my wife as a picture on her profile.

Hope this will help someone.

The tip for the solution came from https://bugs.launchpad.net/mugshot/+bug/1402036